# Zone 7 fruit trees that will thrive in wet soil

Tags: fruit-trees

I'm looking to get a line of fruit trees growing at the edge of my property, which:

- is in Zone 7, Northern Virginia
- is not well drained / is often moist
- gets full sun
- is about 100ft of linear space (E.g. I want to plant X number of trees in a 100ft straight line on the edge of the property, but I would also be open to doing a "checkerboard" pattern, so two rows of trees, staggered, along the 100ft line.)

Interested in:

- pear (I've read that the P. betulaefolia rootstock is good for wet soil)
- apple
- others?

Please share your suggestions!